# Retrieving URL of Facebook profile picture

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code that has a correct output:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,first_name,email,gender,birthday,picture.url' );
$response = $request->execute();
```

OUTPUT:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object ( [backingData:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1412361249046879 [first_name] => Do [email] => xxxx@xxxx.com [gender] => male [birthday] => 06/30/1984 [picture] => stdClass Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [url] => https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/t1.0-1/p50x50/10406555_1412406989042185_8978818317524743009_t.jpg ) ) ) )
```

Then I set variables to call later in my html:

```
  $uid = $response->getGraphObject()->getProperty('id');
  $name = $response->getGraphObject()->getProperty('first_name');
  $email = $response->getGraphObject()->getProperty('email');
  **$pic = $response->getGraphObject()->getProperty('picture.data.url');**
  $sex = $response->getGraphObject()->getProperty('gender');
  $bday = $response->getGraphObject()->getProperty('birthday');
```

The problem is the $pic variable doesn't work. I don't understand how to call the variable that is further down the GraphObject tree (ie. picture->data->url)

Comment: Picture is not a field. It is an edge. Try to request /me/picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,first_name,email,gender,birthday,picture.url' );
$response = $request->execute();      
$array = $response->getResponse();
$pic = $array->picture->data->url;
```

Here is what ended up solving it. I had to stop using the getGraphObject() function and just use the standard getResponse() so that I could treat it more like a regular array. Hope this helps somebody out.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me 6 years later :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont call it like this:

```
$pic = $response->getGraphObject()->getProperty('picture')->data->url;
```

OR use FQL with FB SDK

```
$config = array(
  'appId'  => APP_ID,
  'secret' => API_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,

);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT uid,email, pic, first_name, last_name, birthday, sex FROM user WHERE uid = ".$uid.""
    );

$result = $result = $facebook->api($params);
```

Here is the full [table of user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) and official [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0).
I hope this helps.

Warning: But FQL it will be removed from new version of FB API.

Comment: Or try it like this: $picObj = $response->getGraphObject()->getProperty('picture'); $pic = $picObj->data->url;

Comment: I'd like to avoid FQL because of its short life expectancy. I tried what you have above and that didn't work either. I've been combing through the FB PHP SDK documentation all day and haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: FQL will be around until v2.1 of the Graph API, meaning April 30th, 2016